# SubscribeOn with TestScheduler fails to Subscribe until 2nd Tick

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I'm seeing the following inconsistent behavior when calling SubscribeOn with a TestScheduler.

```
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var subject = new Subject<int>();

        testScheduler.Schedule(() => subject.OnNext(1));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1), () => subject.OnNext(2));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(2), () => subject.OnNext(3));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(3), () => subject.OnNext(4));

        subject
            .SubscribeOn(testScheduler)
            .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        testScheduler.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Produces the Output:

```
3
4
```

However if you subscribe to the observer before scheduling then it works as expected.

```
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var subject = new Subject<int>();

        subject
            .SubscribeOn(testScheduler)
            .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        testScheduler.Schedule(() => subject.OnNext(1));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1), () => subject.OnNext(2));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(2), () => subject.OnNext(3));
        testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(3), () => subject.OnNext(4));


        testScheduler.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Produces Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Can anyone explain this behavior, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe is happening is that you effectively scheduling two things to happen at the same point in time. Both the initial `OnNext(1)` call and the subscription i.e. `SubscribeOn` are scheduled to occur implicitly at tick 0.

When two things are scheduled to occur at the same time, the thing that was scheduled first will run first, then the second etc. They will all see the same time on the virtual clock, but it is single threaded so only one thing can be run at a time.

In your first example you effectively have a journal of actions as follows

```
Time (in Ticks) Action
---------------------------
       0        () => subject.OnNext(1)
       0        () => subject.Subscribe(..)
10000000        () => subject.OnNext(2)
20000000        () => subject.OnNext(3)
30000000        () => subject.OnNext(4)
```

In your second example the journal looks more like this

```
Time (in Ticks) Action
---------------------------
       0        () => subject.Subscribe(..)
       0        () => subject.OnNext(1)
10000000        () => subject.OnNext(2)
20000000        () => subject.OnNext(3)
30000000        () => subject.OnNext(4)
```

So while the times for the subscription and the OnNext are the same, the order is different. It might help to think of the `testScheduler.Start();` as looping over that journal executing actions and advancing the clock. With this in mind it should be clear why you dont see the value 1 in your first example.

I have two suggestions:

- use the `TestScheduler` to create your Observable Sequences instead of Subjects.
- Avoid scheduling things at time 0 in your tests. It is an unlikely real world thing to happen, and it makes for odd looking tests (where you test for things being off by one)

You could rewrite your test like this

```
var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
var observer = testScheduler.CreateObserver<int>();
var sequence = testScheduler.CreateHotObservable(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks, 1),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).Ticks, 2),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).Ticks, 3),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4).Ticks, 4)
    );

sequence
    .SubscribeOn(testScheduler)
    .Subscribe(observer);
testScheduler.Start();

var expected = new[]
{
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks, 1),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).Ticks, 2),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).Ticks, 3),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4).Ticks, 4),
};
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, observer.Messages);
```

If you would like to reduce the noise in the code, you can subclass the `ReactiveTest` class (in Rx-testing) so you have direct access to the `OnNext` factory method and its siblings `OnError` + `OnCompleted`. You can also do some things around ticks and TimeSpans to reduce the noise there.

Comment: I edit my question to show that it actually misses the times scheduled at the 0 tick and the 1 tick. I'm guessing what you said still holds true, but the scheduleOn happens at the 1 tick for some reason?